# Paypal continue shopping button on Cart Page

Tags: paypal

I have set up a simple web page with numerous add to cart buttons (all created in Paypal).

When you click the add to cart button you are directed to the Paypal cart. You can either check out or continue shopping which is fine.

Is there anyway to rename the 'continue shopping' button to something else. Continue shopping does not really fit with what my website is. I would like for it to be renamed 'Add another service'.

Alternatively is there a way to add the product to the cart without displaying the cart itself each time and then the user can continue to add products from the page they were on. Once completed they can click the view cart button and review the cart then.

Any help you be appreciated,
Graham